# How to display number + sign in in character chains

Tags: libreoffice

I try to display the + sign of the number in the following character chains in G3 I want to see (-4)+(+4)= :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## You can define your own cell format

1. Right click on the cell B3 and select **Format Cells...**. The Format Cells window will open.
2. Under Category, select **user defined**
3. In the **Format Code** box enter "+0;-0;0" without the quotes.

As shown in the picture below:

[image]

Use the same cell format in other cells where you need it. The new format will be saved with this file. You may have to define it again for another file.

To show the plus sign in the formula in the cell G3 above enter number format inside the formula as:

```
="("&TEXT(A3,"+0;-0;0")&")+("&TEXT(B3,"+0;-0;0")&")="
```

Reference: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/gu/text/shared/01/05020301.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=UNIX

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I want. First it has a side effect that now I see +0 or just 0 is enough. But still not have (+4) in (-4)+(4). You may can correct my english my question was not clear. Thank's again.

Answer (score 0):

On solution is to use TEXTE(B3;"+#;-#;0") :

[image]